# Trigger an event related function only once

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible, when button triggers this action, it stays on `!this.lastMeasure`? Because when I click it again, it goes back to the last state. I want it to stay on the new state.

```js
changeMeasure() {
  this.lastMeasure = !this.lastMeasure
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just set it to false? `this.lastMeasure = false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue provides **event modifiers** for the `v-on` directive. One of these **event modifiers** is **.once**, it rules the associated events to be triggered at most once.

You can use this **event modifier** like :

```html
<!-- the click event will be triggered at most once -->
<a v-on:click.once="doThis"></a>
```

Then in your case, you may use something like :

```html
<!-- '@' is the shorthand for 'v-on:' -->
<button @click.once="changeMeasure">I am the button</button>
```

[source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)